# FreeBSD csh, TAB to show available choices?

Tags: freebsd, autocomplete, tcsh, csh

How can i configure `csh` or `tcsh` to show available choices by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, just like bash?

Comment: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/turn-on-autocomplete-for-filesystem.5486/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the `tcsh/csh` man page you'll find a option under "completion":

```
set autolist
```

Add this to your `.cshrc` file to enable this feature.

#### A word on tcsh/csh

This shell really shouldn't be used, both are sub-par shells by today's standards and are wrought with poorly implemented features. You should be using Bash, Zsh, Ksh, or something else entirely.